# Program Won't Show in the Foreground When I Click the Task Manager

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Forms Application.  It basically reads files from one directory and writes them to another.  A lot of files.  In the application, I have a label that says "Processing (filename)" and it updates as expected.  The problem is that when I put another program in the foreground - any other program such as Firefox, Windows Explorer, whatever - I see my application in the task manager however I get no response when I click on it.  Further, the only way to see my program is to minimize every other window on the screen.  How can I fix this?  I want the program to pop to the top of all the windows when I click on it in the Task Manager.  I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Background Worker? This will allow the UI thread free to do UI work. See - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx#Examples

Comment: Thank you, Kevin.  I thought that as long as the interface was doing something with the UI, then it would respond to the task manager.  Maybe not so much....     I'll look into that.  Thanks.